# UIDatePicker as UITextField.inputView not showing correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uidatepicker

I have a `textField` and its `inputView` as an `UIDatePicker`

Using `.inline` would still work fine when `UIDatePicker` is set as as `UITextField.inputView` but major issue that for some reason UIKit hard-limits the keyboard height to some (seems like) calculated value

Because UI is laid out to use full width, this pushes picker's header view to something like 6pt and thus render it unusable, since you can't easily tap to change the month/year.

Here you can see it

[image: UIDatePicker example]

To fixed this you could just set:

```
datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
```

[image: IDatePicker example .wheels]

Do you know if there is a way of still using `.inline` and still can use the `UIDatePicker()`?

Comment: Hi there! Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi Zee, I have not find a solution.

Comment: @Zee, You can check the answer written by swiftsquirrel

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with the same issue and recently figured out the answer: basically, the `.inline` style of `UIDatePicker()` is not made to function as an `inputView` for `UITextField()`. The display behavior you are seeing is actually correct, in that the `.inline` style is behaving as intended by Apple.

This style expects you to also be using the `UIDatePicker()`, not `UITextField()`, to display the current date value inline as part of your UI. So, when you call it up as an `inputView`, that input view is actually displaying the current value. It's not that the picker is somehow squished or forced offscreen. When you tap that value (if your finger is small enough lol), it will display the calendar picker, and the calendar picker will behave as you'd expect.

I detail this a little more in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77345690/22775442). I think if you want the calendar picker, you're going to have to use `UIDatePicker()` to display the value as well, as opposed to `UITextField()`. Otherwise you're stuck with `.wheels`.

Comment: I'll give your solution a try, and I hope it helps other users as well.
I appreciate your help!